# How can I drop a SqlServer Backup Device using SMO in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I can drop a SqlServer Backup Device using SQL-DMO using the following pseudo-code:

```
SQLDMO.SQLServer2 server = New SQLDMO.SQLServer2();
server.Connect("myserver");
server.BackupDevices.Remove("mybackupdevice");
File.Delete(mybackupdevicephysicallocation);
```

`SMO.Server.BackupDevices` does not appear to have a Remove() method, so how can I drop a BackupDevice using SMO?

I'm hoping that I've just missed something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BackupDevice.Drop](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backupdevice.drop%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
Server server = new Server("localhost");
BackupDevice device = server.BackupDevices["devicename"];
device.Drop();
```

Comment: @remus-rusanu:  Thanks much!  I'm embarrassed at how easy that is.